# Android Webview scroll to bottom programmatically (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I am trying to reach bottom of a Webview.
I am getting the height of Webview inside onPageFinished() method by,

```
override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {

                Log.d("webview_total_height", "height " + view!!.contentHeight)
                height = view!!.contentHeight
            }
```

And on button click I am trying to reach to bottom by,

```
wvMain.scrollTo(0, height)
```

But it's scrolling to somewhere middle of webview, not reaching bottom

How will I reach to the bottom of webview?

Comment: try `view.scrollTo(0, view.getContentHeight());`

Comment: Here, view is webview, right?

Comment: yes, it is webview

Comment: If you can extend `WebView` try overriding and exposing protected method [computeVerticalScrollRange()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#computeVerticalScrollRange()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace

```
wvMain.scrollTo(0, height)
```

By

```
wvMain.scrollTo(0, height * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density.toInt())
```

By this you will get actual height of WebView in pixels as per device screen density

I guess you will get your desired result.

Comment: Right, it also makes sens to wait for the web content to load.